# WinRT WebView does not update the current URL based on HTML5 pushState?

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

The WinRT [`WebView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) control in both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 does not update its [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.source) property in response to `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState`, which can modify the current URL from JavaScript without actually navigating to a different page.

You can easily verify this by creating a new blank app, adding a `WebView` control named *WebView* to *MainPage.xaml* and replacing the constructor with the following:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    timer.Tick += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("WebView.Source: " + WebView.Source);
    timer.Start();

    // you could also replace the URL with a simpler demo page like this one:
    // http://www.skjapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/HistoryAPI-pushState.htm
    WebView.Navigate(new Uri("http://try.discourse.org"));
}
```

Opening any discussion thread on Discourse will not update `WebView.Source`. The native IE browser handles this correctly, and strange enough the old Windows Phone Silverlight [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control does as well.

So, am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to get the current URL of a `WebView` that properly supports the HTML5 history API?

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Comment: In my case the solution was to inject some JavaScript when the page is loaded, so that the use of the History API is skipped. You need to understand how Discourse is achieving that, and with which JavaScript objects/functions (looking at source code, setting breakpoints, finding functions in the `window` variable). Then override those functions and make them simply change the href with `window.location.href = ` etc. This is just a hint, in my case I managed to do it in 2 hours.